# EIdHTTPProtocolException doesn't raise exception

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-xe4

I'm trying to post data from a old delphi application on a web mvc app webapi (.net and c#) with authentication filters. If the password is wrong return 401 but the exception is not raised, the result is empty. Now I am forced to manually check the response code! The HTTPOptions are okay.

```
try
  Result := IdHTTP.Post(requestUrl, JsonToSend);
  //In this way I fixed this problem but it's very annoying! :(
  //if (IdHTTP.ResponseCode<>200) then  raise Exception.Create(IdHTTP.ResponseText);
except
  on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
    begin
      raise Exception.Create(E.Message);
    end;
  on E : Exception do
    raise Exception.Create(e.Message);
end;
```

Comment: It's very difficult to understand what you are trying to do here. From your description it seems that EIdHttpProtocolException is never raised. So what? Your raised the exception (with text IdHttp.ResponseText) will be trapped by the on E: Exception and then reraised. It also seems that "password is wrong" doesn't raise any exception at all.

Comment: I'm sorry, I must raise manually because EIdHttpProtocolException is never raised! Why is never raised? :(
Now I commented my fix.

Comment: It's not always possible to understand what people were thinking. Many times things don't work the way you want them to, so if things don't work the way you think they should have worked, code for what you've got. In your case, check the ResponseCode for 401 if that's what you're concerned about.

Comment: This is what programming is about. It isn't annoying, it's normal.

Comment: The annoying thing is that it is not documented which exceptions can be raised and when.

Comment: Because the rules for when an exception is raised or not raised depend on the particular response code that is being received and how it is processed.  `TIdHTTP`'s handling for 401 actually involves quite a bit of internally logic before it makes that decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Response code 401 is *NOT* an HTTP error, which is why `EIdHTTPProtocolException` is not raised right away.  401 is the server's way of asking the client for authentication credentials.  `TIdHTTP` handles 401 by checking the following criteria:

1. the number of authentication attempts has not yet exceeded the value of the `TIdHTTP.MaxAuthRetries` property (3 by default).
2. the `TIdHTTP.Response.WWWAuthenticate` property specifies an authentication scheme that `TIdHTTP` recognizes, or a `TIdHTTP.OnSelectAuthorization` event handler is assigned and returns an authentication class type in its `AuthenticationClass` output parameter.
3. a `TIdHTTP.OnAuthorization` event handler is assigned and returns True in its `Handled` output parameter (after obtaining updated credentials from the user), or the `TIdHTTP.Request.Password` property is not blank.
4. the selected authorization scheme has not run out of steps yet (1 for `BASIC`, 3 for `NTLM`, etc).

If any of the above criteria is not OK, then `EIdHTTPProtocolException` will be raised, unless you either:

1. enable the `hoNoProtocolErrorException` flag in the `TIdHTTP.HTTPOptions` property.
2. specify 401 in the `AIgnoreReplies` parameter of `TIdHTTP.DoRequest()` (`TIdHTTP.Post()` does not expose that parameter, but `TIdHTTP.Get()` does).

In either of those cases, the current request simply ends without error, and you will have to manually check the `TIdHTTP.ResponseCode` property.

On the other hand, if the above criteria is OK, and the `hoInProcessAuth` parameter is enabled in the `TIdHTTP.HTTPOptions` property, then the current request is retried with (potentially updated) authentication credentials.  But if `hoInProcessAuth` is not enabled, then the current request simply ends without error, and you will have to manually check the `TIdHTTP.ResponseCode` property.  `hoInProcessAuth` is not enabled by default, so this is the likely branch where your `Post` request ends up.

The fact that the server is returning 401 means the server expects authentication, so you should handle it.  Enable `hoInProcessAuth` and handle the `OnSelectAuthorization` and `OnAuthorization` events as needed so requests can be retried each time new credentials are provided by the user.

But, if you really want 401 to raise an exception, enable `hoInProcessAuth` and do not handle the events at all.  Or, just keep doing what you are already doing.